# How to translate the function

Tags: javascript

Write a function translate() that will translate a text into "rövarspråket". That is, double every consonant and place an occurrence of "o" in between. For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon"

Comment: As a swede I approve of this function.

Comment: this site is for seeking answers to specific problems with existing pieces of code.  It does not exist to tell you how to write the code in the first place.

Comment: One approach would be to loop over the characters in the input string, check if each one is a consonant or not, then do the right thing. By the way, could you give your question a title saying what it's actually about?

Answer (score 1):

Simple regex replacement - but you need to decide for yourself whether you want to treat [`Y`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y#English) as a vowel or as a consonant:

```
function translate(text, cons, char) {
    // translate text into "rövarspråket"
    // text - string
    // cons (optional) - regex with character list to be replaced, must have 1 group
    // char (optional) - character to insert between duplicated cons
    cons = cons || /([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])/ig;  // excluding y by default
    char = char || 'o';
    return text.replace(cons, '$1' + char + '$1');
}

console.log(translate("this is fun"));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ck484g0o/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkConsonants(letterToCheck) {
    var consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    var isConsonant = false;

    for (i = 0; i < consonants.length; i++) {
        if (letterToCheck == consonants[i]) {
            isConsonant = true;
        }
    }
    return isConsonant;
}

function translate(funString, letterO) {

    console.log('The original string is: "' + funString + '"');
    console.log('The separator is: "' + letterO + '"');

    var newString = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < funString.length; i++) {
        if (checkConsonants(funString[i])) {
            newString += funString[i] + letterO + funString[i];
        } else {
            newString += funString[i];
        }
    }
    console.log('The "rövarspråket" result is: ' + '"' + newString + '"');
}

translate('this is fun', 'o');
```

Take a look of this.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lisafrench/CmHH8/)

Answer (score 0):

I'll go for attempting the minimum amount of code while also taking uppercase letters at the beginning of words into account...

```
function translate(fullString) {    
    cons=new Array("b","B","c","C","d","D","f","F","g","G","h","H","j","J","k","K","l","L","m","M","n","N","p","P","q","Q","r","R","s","S","t","T","v","V","w","W","x","X","y","Y","z","Z");
    for(x in cons) {
        fullString=fullString.replace(new RegExp(cons[x], 'g'), cons[x] + "o" + cons[x].toLowerCase());
    }
    return fullString;
}
```

I'm sure someone with a better knowledge of regex than me could also reduce the size of the array :-)